# Cannot view Tag Properties in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part, web-part-property

I created a list from a spreadsheet and added a view with a Text Filter. I want to use parameters to create the wildcard filter.  I did this on one site already in the same SharePoint 2016 on Premises tenant using the same spreadsheet.

When I edit the file in SharePoint Designer 2013, I right click the XsltListViewWebPart tag and choose Tag Properties whereupon the Page Properties dialog shows.  I need to be able to get the XsltListViewWebPart to show by editing the tag properties. Both sites use the Team Site template and both feature sets are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was related to the Oslo.master page.  This was the only difference I could find so I switched it to Seattle.master under site settings and the tag properties worked immediately.  I was able to create the wildcard parameter for my list. I hope this helps someone.